# Find the appropriate strings to use for azure Python 3.6 API for azure

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to set up reading event hub messages via the Azure event hub API.

I believe I have the event hub and storage containers set up properly.  But I don't know how to find the exact information it's looking for here....

connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>'

consumer_group = '<< CONSUMER GROUP >>'

eventhub_name = '<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>'

storage_connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING OF THE STORAGE >>'

container_name = '<< STORAGE CONTAINER NAME>>'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. [Get the EnvetEvent Hub Namespace connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string#get-connection-string-from-the-portal)

   a. Sign in to Azure portal.

   b. Select **All services** on the left navigational menu.

   c. Select **Event Hubs** in the **Analytics** section.

   d. In the list of event hubs, select your event hub.

   e. Get connection string
     [image]
2. Get your Event Hub name
   [image]
3. Get the storage  Container Name
   [image]
   [image]
4. Get the storage  Container connection string. If you know the container in one storage account, please refer to the following steps to [get the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string?#view-and-copy-a-connection-string)

   a. Locate your storage account.

   b. Get connection string
    [image]

Otherwise, please reset a container fro the event hub then you use the above steps to get the connection string.
[image]

5. Consumer group
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: This is super helpful.  Thanks.  However, when I try to turn on the "Capture" slider to ON in step 3, it's grayed out.

Comment: Could you please provide the error picture and tell me what you want to do?